# What kind of digital signatures are used in an SMS?

Tags: android, sms, digital-signature

What kind of digital signatures are used specifically in signing an SMS? In terms of what is attached and how it is encrypted (sha, md5, etc.).

Also, how does one look for them in, say, Android?

(I found this link [Verifying a Digital Signature](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/versig.html) but it doesn't resolve all my doubts) 
'

**Edit**: The problem at hand is to classify them as spam or not spam. 
Typically, those used in say banking solutions, trusted companies, etc. would be signed. 
Apart from sms received from a genuine phone user, unsigned SMS are considered spam.

As I mentioned in my reply in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020144/spam-protection-algorithm-for-sms/8020771#8020771)  quoting from this pdf: [Content Based SMS Spam Filtering](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.7578&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (I think it's a research paper) :

> The most popular techniques used to reduce spam nowadays include the following ones.
>
> ...
>
> **Digital signatures**- Messages without a digital signature are
>   considered spam. Digital signatures can be provided by the sender or
>   the service provider.

Comment: Normal SMS is not encrypted or signed. Are you talking about some kind of special SMS implementation such as encrypted SMS as used in some banking solutions?

Comment: yup, i am talking about those SMS which are sent automatically, and the problem at hand is to classify them as spam or not spam, those used in say banking solutions, trusted companies would be signed. apart from sms received from a genuine phone user unsigned sms are considered spam

Comment: @Optimus Are you sure that banking SMS are indeed signed ? In my experience I never saw a signature on a banking SMS...

Comment: @Optimus BTW: the paper talks about possibilities in dealing with spam via SMS... although it is more theoretical since that would usually need a change the SMS specification...

Comment: yup, i took the time to read it in detail, it does not suggest whether or not SMS are digitally signed yet.

Comment: @Yahia: in that case, should i delete this post? or leave it for when we have digitally signed sms in future, (there seems to be some talk about it)

Comment: @Optimus I am not the authority on SMS so perhaps there is something I don't know... but from my POV there no such thing as a digital signature in SMS except when you implement both (sender and receiver) yourself and somehow put the signature into the SMS body itself... leave it for 1-2 days... if nobody comes up then ask a moderator to close it (this way others at least can learn that there is no SMS digital signature)